# How do you get to the area behind the savepoint in Mizuhagawa District's Construction site?

Tags: scarlet-nexus

There are two environment materials that can be picked up in that area... but I can't seem to find a way to reach the area. How do I get there? Area highlighted in yellow in image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the north end of the region you indicated, there's a fence whose top is visibly bent down. With Kasane at least (I don't know if Kaito controls any differently), you can do an X+A attack (the uppercut-type attack) to get enough height to clear the fence and land on the other side. (If you've unlocked the double jump in the Brain Map skill tree, you can use that, too.)

At the south end of that section, you'll have to do this gain to access the southernmost tip of the indicated region. You can then retrace your steps to return to the main area.

Answer (score 1):

You can double jump on broken fences to get in there.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What fences exactly? Can you provide an image of them if possible?